# How to create a phase shift

Tags: shift, phase

I have an input voltage of 230V 50Hz which runs through a transformer the output of which is a 50A 50Hz current, i need to create and control a phase shift. Can it be done ?
The solution can be digital or analog and the phase shift can be introduced before or after the transformer.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Are you looking to do this with a microprocessor?

Comment: Sorry, this question was meant for the electrical engineering site. I'd like to do this with a microprocessor/microcontroller though, if you have anything in mind i'm open for suggestions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks more like an [electronics.se] question.